# Eclipse - install software dependencies

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install [efxclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html) into Eclipse Juno.  I have followed the steps in the link and am running into a dependency error along the lines of "Missing requirements: package javax annotation 1.2.0".  How do I go about finding this dependency.  Obviously it is a jar but I can't find it anywhere (Maven repos, etc.), and even if I did, where would I put it so Eclipse would pick it up during the software install?

This is one area of eclipse that I absolutely hate because it gives little or no info about how to find the dependency, and info is scare about resolving these dependency issues.  Is their a general approach to solving Eclipse software dependency issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Version 1.2 of the javax.annotation plugin is in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna). Efxclipse requires Eclipse 4.4

Comment: Adding to that, Juno is 4.2.x.

Comment: Would be nice if the installer mentioned that!